# Excel QueryTable on Text File source fails with Jet OLEDB Connect String

Tags: vba, excel, text-files, oledb

Using VBA, I am trying to create an Excel querytable to provide a subset of data from a text file.  I would like to use a Jet OLEDB connection string as the querytable `Connection`.  Why does this fail?

Here is the procedure.

```
Sub OledbTest1()  'FAILS.
'Create querytable with oledb connect string.
    Const strConn = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\RSJCB\Desktop\;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""
    Dim wsht As Worksheet
    Set wsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add()
    With wsht
        'The next line errors with 1004: Application-defined of object-defined error
        .QueryTables.Add strConn, .Range("A1"), "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [TestFile.csv]"
        .QueryTables(1).Refresh
    End With
    Set wsht = Nothing
End Sub
```

The connection string works if I use it to create an ADO recordset, and then use that recordset as the querytable `Connection`.

```
Sub OledbTest2()  'SUCCEEDS.
'Create querytable with ado recordset opened using oledb connect string.
    Const strConn = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\RSJCB\Desktop\;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""
    Const strSql = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [TestFile.csv]"
    Dim wsht As Worksheet
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.Open strSql, strConn
    Set wsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add()
    With wsht
        'The next line errors with 1004: Application-defined of object-defined error
        .QueryTables.Add rst, .Range("A1")
        .QueryTables(1).Refresh
    End With
    Set wsht = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

It also works if I use a Microsoft Text ODBC Driver connection string as the querytable `Connection`.  However, this appears to work a little slower, and I'm reading 700K records in the actual code.  Further, I've never been able to make an OLEDB connection to a querytable and would like to know how to do it.

```
Sub OdbcTestQtbl()  'SUCCEEDS.
'Create querytable with odbc connect string.
    Const strConn = _
        "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & _
        "Dbq=C:\Users\RSJCB\Desktop\;" & _
        "Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"
    Dim wsht As Worksheet
    Set wsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add()
    With wsht
        .QueryTables.Add "ODBC;" & strConn, .Range("A1"), "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [TestFile.csv]"
        .QueryTables(1).Refresh
    End With
    Set wsht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Greatly appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to let Excel know that the driver is an OLEDB driver.  Just append the (apparently undocumented) provider specifier to the start of the connection string:

```
.QueryTables.Add "OLEDB;" & strConn, .Range("A1"), "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [TestFile.csv]"
```

Comment: Yep, that works.  Can't believe I didn't try that.  The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837764.aspx) does specify the requirement for "ODBC;" at the beginning of an ODBC connections string, but doesn't specify it for OLEDB. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JBStovers - To be honest, it was more of a "I wonder if this will work" stab in the dark.